# What's the difference between OS version reported by uname vs. /etc/debian_version

Tags: debian, version

What's the difference between the Debian versions reported by `uname` vs what's in the file `/etc/debian_version`?
E.g.:

```
user@bldsvr:~$ uname -a
Linux sv-debbld-22 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
user@bldsvr:~$ cat /etc/debian_version
9.9
```

Comment: @Freddy - yes, it does; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem that it gives infos about the distribution, `uname` actually displays information about the running kernel.
It can deceive you as on some (rare) virtualization env, guests machines can use the kernel of the host. You can see an ubuntu vm running a centos kernel..

`/etc/debian_version` is also deceptive as many distribution are based on debian and keeps this file, such as ubuntu.

The most reliable tool to get the distribution and it's version is `lsb_release`, though it's not always installed by default.

Installation instructions here (not my website): https://www.computerhope.com/unix/lsb_release.htm

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu.

```
mac2011-linux% cat /etc/debian_version 
bullseye/sid
mac2011-linux% uname -a
Linux mac2011-linux 5.8.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 17:18:36 UTC 2021
```

I conclude that `uname` is more accurate.

Comment: not exactly, in bookworm : `uname -a` results in `Linux cbb8b7e7e492 5.15.49-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Sep 13 xx:xx:xx UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`